# How do I retrieve only lines with specific words or phrases?

Tags: ruby

I need to read a file in a series of lines, and then
retrieve specific lines depending on words that are contained
in them. How can I do this?

So far I read the lines like this:

```
lines = File.readlines("myfile.txt")
```

Now, I need to scan for lines that contain "red", "rabbit", "blue". I want to do this part in as few lines of code as possible.

So if my file was:

```
the red queen of hearts.
yet another sentence.
and this has no relevant words.
the blue sky
the white chocolate rabbit.
another irrelevant line.
```

I would like to see only the lines:

```
the red queen of hearts.
the blue sky
the white chocolate rabbit.
```

Comment: I suppose you don't want lines that contain the strings "red", etc. You want lines that contain them as words. See my comment on floatless's answer.

Comment: Duplicate of [Finding lines in a text file matching a regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002868/finding-lines-in-a-text-file-matching-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lines = File.readlines("myfile.txt").grep(/red|rabbit|blue/)
```

Comment: This will match lines that include "Fred", "jackrabbit", "bluer". The regex should be `/\b(?:red|rabbit|blue)\b/`.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are your friend. They will make quick work of this task.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm

You would want a regex along the lines of

```
/^.*(red|rabbit|blue).*$/
```

The `^` means start of line, the `.*` means match anything, `(red|rabbit|blue)` means exactly what you think it means, and lastly the `$` means end of line.

Answer (score 0):

I think an each loop would be best in this situation:

```
lines.each do |line|
    if line.include? red or rabbit or blue
        puts line
    end
end
```

Give that a shot.